# How to stop horizontal movement in jQuery Nestable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, jquery-nestable

I am using this plugin `https://github.com/dbushell/Nestable`

I have tried commenting various core code in it which it has helper comments like horizontal and vertical but still I am clueless on how to stop the horizontal dragging.

Let me elaborarte I only want vertical movements of elements and no horizontal movements of elements of which will lead to parent-child scenario
see the pic below
[image]

Comment: can you provide your code?

Comment: If they aren't nested how would you get  parent/child relationship? If all you want is a sortable list, you are using the wrong tool for the job

Comment: I mean I want to nest them in vertical movements only , not the horizontal movements which lead to parent child relationship, In short I only want to move them strictly up and down only

Comment: Well that nestable plugin is meant for different purpose. Lots of other scripts you can use for drag/drop list sorting

Comment: well then kinly suggest one for sortable list except jquery ui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well found the answer , in case any one finds a flaw then please comment

`$(element).nestable({
     maxDepth: 1,
 });`

Answer (score 0):

this is a tree view if you want to just align them equally you can simply use ul , li but if you have an object and it has parent/child nodes and you want to show them as a tree view except not having the indent then simply remove the indent with css or maybe there is a method or property in nestable to set amount of indent to whatever you want